# Why WinBase.h Provided by Mingw32 Excludes `SetProcessDEPPolicy' for Windows 7?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw32

I discovered that the function definition of `SetProcessDEPPolicy` (in `WinBase.h`) is included only if `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x601`. Why MingW32 sets `_WIN32_WINNT = 0x400` for Windows 7 to exclude the definition? I checked the `kernel32.dll` of Windows 7), and it contains `SetProcessDEPPolicy` function all right.

Comment: `0x400` means NT4. `0x601` is win7. Have you tried defining the macro yourself? Alternatively you can target a lower version and find the function with `GetProcAddress`, but NT4 seems absurdly low.

Comment: @asveikau: This is not true when compiled with Mingw32

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my comment.  What I was trying to say is that Mingw32 is probably set up to target NT4 by default.  You can define that macro to be whatever you want.

Comment: MinGW presumably defaults to 0x0400 so that the generated program will be runnable on a wide variety of Windows machines - not just machines that are of the same (or newer) version of Windows as the build machine. I thought that MSVC did the same, but it looks like MSVC (rather the SDK) defaults to setting `_WIN32_WINNT` to the latest API version in the SDK being used, which might not be the version of Windows being used to build the program. Strictly speaking, you should explicitly set `_WIN32_WINNT` to the API version that your application requires.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal and exactly how it's supposed to be.

In your app, you need to set `_WIN32_WINNT` to the version of Windows you are targetting so you get the appropriate API.

From MSDN:

> To compile an application that calls this function, define `_WIN32_WINNT` as 0x0600 or later.

MingW most likely sets a sensible default (of NT4.0) allowing you to increase it if required.

Answer (score 1):

> I discovered that the function definition of SetProcessDEPPolicy (in
>   WinBase.h) is included only if _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x601.

However, on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says you need to define it as `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x600` for Windows Vista with SP1, and later. `0x601` is for Window 7. Read more about Windows Headers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

With every new version of Windows, the Windows API changes to add new functions. The Windows header files tells the compiler which function is available on which version of Windows.

> Why MingW32 sets _WIN32_WINNT = 0x400 for Windows 7 to exclude the definition?

Because if it doesn't, then all applications compiled with MingW will most likely work only on Window 7 and later.

When you define `_WIN32_WINNT` in your project, you are simply telling the compiler which version of Windows you are targeting. If you define it as `0x0601` to be able to call functions like `SetProcessDEPPolicy` then your application won't run on earlier versions of Windows.

To support as many versions of Windows as possible you need to downgrade `_WIN32_WINNT` to the lowest version of Windows you want your application to run on. This will make sure that your application is using an API that is common and available for the version you are targeting and later. But this will exclude all "new" functions that are introduced on later versions of Windows.

MingW, by defaults, sets `_WIN32_WINNT = 0x400` to make your application work on all possible versions of Windows. However, if your application need to call a function that is available on a specific version of Windows, then you need to change `_WIN32_WINNT` to the appropriate version to be able to do that.